# Joomla: correct way to sanitize file data

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am writing import script from csv files and I need to validate data, most of the data is strings so I want to use something like Jinput to sanitize it.

Is there is something Joomla already have for this purpose?

It would be ideal to have something like

```
$field = JSanitizer::get($data/*array with data*/, "fieldname"/*name of field*/, 
    'string'/*type of data*/, 'null'/*default value*/);
```

Also I would need it to work both in Joomla 2.5 and 3.0 versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for `JFilterInput::clean()` This would work as follows:

```
$field = JFilterInput::clean($data[$fieldname], 'filter');
```

This does not give a way to set a default value, so you would have to handle that afterwards. This should be the same filtering that is typically done with JInput as well as on JForm elements if you write custom components.

I can't seem to find a good list of all the filters, but you can see an old version of the source here: http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JFilterInput/clean. Most recent version of the function starts at line 162 here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php

Note also that you want to pull the field out of the data array yourself. You can actually send it the entire array without a filter setting and it should at least check the entire array for XSS and other issues. If you want more nuanced filtering for integers and such, it would best to do it field by field.

Comment: Thank you this is almost exactly what I've searched for.

Comment: This generates a warning about using a non-static method, Joomla 3.7.9.  Use it as per Tom's post below.

Answer (score 2):

```
$field = JFilterInput::clean($data[$fieldname], 'filter');
```

will fire a notice
    "Non-static method JFilterInput::clean() should not be called statically"
You should initiate this with JFilterInput::getInstance() first and call it dynamically e.g.:

```
$field = JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($data[$fieldname], 'filter');
```

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines) and use something like this before parsing file :
 `$string = JRequest::getString( 'description' );` 
This should work across all version since 1.5

There has been some github projects to implement [html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as plugin, i found [this](https://github.com/elpaso/joomla-fap-25/tree/master/release), but havent chance to tested it, but it should work though.

Comment: JRequest is used to retrieve data from request, I am parsing csv data which is uploaded by file so I need something else that would accept array with data or a single variable to sanitize.

Comment: And also in Joomla 2.5 JRequest is deprecated, Jinput should be used instead.